# How to insert tags with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to insert in an aspx page the following code:

```
</ul>
</li>
<li class="xxx" style="width: 650px; float: left; list-style: none outside none;">
<ul class="yyy">
```

The problem is that, serverside, it raises a problem (sharepoint...)

What I would like to do, is to insert this code client side with a javascript script. How can I insert it using javascript ? I don't think innerHTML could do this work as it would put it inside another tag (div for instance).

Thank you !

Comment: What problem did this raise? Not sure I understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
liTag = document.getElementByName("tagsid")

newtag = document.createElement('new element name eg li here');

liTag.appendChild(newTag);
```

of for text nodes use `createTextNode` instead.

Comment: Forgot - lookup setAttribute to see how to set attribess for the new tag. Also for tables use insertRow. Google them!

Comment: My problem is that I cannot use a "tagsid" parent element, it would be more like a repleacement of the tagsid by another tag (if I put my tag inside tagsid, it would not respect my structure)